# Rendering React component in Angular2 Component template html

Tags: reactjs, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I was trying to render a react component in Angular 2 template. For that i have included the react render dom in the template html of an angular 2 component. Then using the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook of the angular component i have imported the react component script to the template html. The react component renders correctly when we first load the screen or refresh it. But if we change the route and again came back to this route, we can see that the react component is not rendered at the place of the DOM element. All scripts are loading correctly.

Angular 2 component with reacttest.html as the template.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import '../../externalScript.js';
declare var loadExternalScript:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'view',
  templateUrl: '../../views/html/reacttest.html'
})
export class CanvasComponent {

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //loading react components 
    loadExternalScript.readyReactComponents();
   }   
}
```

reacttest.html with react render DOM

```
<!-- Property model dialog -->
  <div id="property-dialog"></div>
```

Script that loads the react component

```
var loadExternalScript = (function() {
  return {
    readyReactComponents: function(){
        System
        .import ('public/react/js/componentPropertiesApp.js')
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
  }
})()
```

Here i am using Angular 2 router for routing, so when we change the route,  angular 2 is changing its component and reload the component and the template html associated with it. All its Lifecycle methods are correctly getting called but some how the react thinks the react component is already loaded in that DOM and it is not re-rendering that. I am also thinking react is caching it some where, because if we refreshes the page then the react component is rendered again.

Comment: Please add plunker